# Cant use Custom Created App in app/Libs CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, path

I have a custom class located at `app/Libs` so its something like this `app/Libs/MyClass.php`

I have tried all the suggested answers here in StackOverflow like: 
 just use `app::uses('MyClass', 'Lib')` it really wont work, im trying to call it inside my `AppController.php` my code is like this:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('MyClass', 'Lib'); 

class AppController extends Controller {
```

and still it wont work it produces an error like this:

```
Warning (2): include(/var/www/mysystem/lib/Cake/Network/Email/MyClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [/var/www/mysystem/lib/Cake/Core/App.php,
```

Why is he looking at the wrong directory? How can I get this to work? Thanks. CakePHP v. 2.++

Answer (score 0):

`"I have a custom class located at app/Libs so its something like this app/Libs/MyClass.php"`.

If that is the case, rename the folder within your app folder to Lib (not Libs) and then declaring `App::uses('MyClass', 'Lib');` in your AppController should work.